# center imported stl file in openscad

Tags: 3d, openscad

I am algorithmically importing stl files in OpensCad and I want the contained models to be always positioned in the center, that is, somehow calculate what their center should be and then use translate to bring that to the point where the x,y,z axes intersect. Is that possible?

Answer (score 5):

1. Import into Cura
2. Right Click | Center Selected Model
3. Select File | Export
4. Export as an STL file
5. Import into OpenSCAD. Model should be centered.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be computing the center of geometry or the center of mass (assuming a uniform weight distribution) of the STL file, and then using that point to calculate the needed translation.

See if this helps:
http://forum.openscad.org/Centre-of-Mass-td14707.html

Answer (score 1):

The question was answered by jpbrown [here](https://www.agisoft.com/forum/index.php?topic=2679.msg14671#msg14671). You need to download [meshlab](http://www.meshlab.net) first. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since I haven't found any openSCAD internal solution, I made a little c program (on linux) which reads an stl file on stdin, finds the max and min x and y coordinates (and the min z coordinate since I do not know the size of my object and I preferred to put it on floor, but it' easy to modify), and writes the centered content on stdout. It only works on binary stl files, though.

```
./center <input.stl >output.stl
```

center.c :

```
#include <assert.h>    // just to make sure
#include <unistd.h>    // To write messages on stderr
#include <stdio.h>     // to read from stdin and write to stdout

char buffer[84];       // to read the header
struct triangle {      // to read all the data in one go
  float sommet[4][3];
  short abc __attribute__((packed));
} __attribute__((packed)) triangles[16*1024*1024];


    int main(void) {
      // trouble shooting info
      fprintf(stderr, "sizeof (short) = %ld, sizeof (int) = %ld, sizeof (float) = %ld, sizeof (struct triangle) = %ld\n", 
              sizeof (short), sizeof (int), sizeof (float), sizeof (struct triangle));
      // Make sure the data has the expected size
      assert(sizeof (short) == 2);
      assert(sizeof (int) == 4);
      assert(sizeof (float) == 4);
      assert(sizeof (struct triangle) == 50);
    
      // read the whole file
      int l=read(0, buffer, 84);
      fprintf(stderr, "read l=%d bytes\n", l);
      assert(l==84);
      fprintf(stderr, "%d triangles\n", ((int*)buffer)[20]);

      int i; 
      for (i=0; i<=20; i++) fprintf(stderr, "%08X ", ((int*)buffer)[i]);
    
      l=read(0, triangles, 1024*1024*50+1);
      assert(l%50==0);
    

      // find min and max values in the 3 dimensions (we dont care about the normal vector in sommet[0])          int j, n=l/50;
      fprintf(stderr, "%d records read\n", n);
      float minx, maxx, miny, maxy, minz, maxz;
    
      minx = maxx = triangles[0].sommet[1][0];
      miny = maxy = triangles[0].sommet[1][1];
      minz = maxz = triangles[0].sommet[1][2];
    
      for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
        for (j = 1; j<=3; j++) {
/*        troubleshooting messages
          fprintf(stderr, "%5d, %d: ", i, j);
          fprintf(stderr, "%08X %c ", ((int*)triangles[i].sommet[j])[0], 'A');
          fprintf(stderr, "%08X %c ", ((int*)triangles[i].sommet[j])[1], 'B');
          fprintf(stderr, "%08X %c ", ((int*)triangles[i].sommet[j])[2], 'C');  
          fprintf(stderr, "%f %c ", triangles[i].sommet[j][0], 'D');
          fprintf(stderr, "%f %c ", triangles[i].sommet[j][1], 'E');
          fprintf(stderr, "%f %c %s\n", triangles[i].sommet[j][2], 'F', "test"); */
          if (triangles[i].sommet[j][0]<minx) minx = triangles[i].sommet[j][0];
          if (triangles[i].sommet[j][0]>maxx) maxx = triangles[i].sommet[j][0];
          if (triangles[i].sommet[j][1]<miny) miny = triangles[i].sommet[j][1];
          if (triangles[i].sommet[j][1]>maxy) maxy = triangles[i].sommet[j][1];
          if (triangles[i].sommet[j][2]<minz) minz = triangles[i].sommet[j][2];
          if (triangles[i].sommet[j][2]>maxz) maxz = triangles[i].sommet[j][2];
        }
      // compute midpoint and substract them from all coordinates (except for normal vector which is not related with object position
      float midx = (minx+maxx)/2, midy = (miny+maxy)/2, lowz = minz;
    
      for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
        for (j = 1; j<=3; j++) {
          triangles[i].sommet[j][0] -= midx;
          triangles[i].sommet[j][1] -= midy;
          triangles[i].sommet[j][2] -= lowz;
        }

      // Print summary info
      fprintf(stderr, "minx = %f, maxx = %f\nminy = %f, maxy = %f\nminz = %f, maxz = %f\n", minx, maxx, miny, maxy, minz, maxz);

      // write result on stdout
      assert(write(1, buffer, 84)==84);
      assert(write(1, triangles, l)==l);
      return 0;
    }
```

compile with

```
gcc -o center center.c -Wall
```